# Removing all digits after 2 decimal places, within an Alert total in JS? (function used to alert total Value)

Tags: javascript

Code snippet below, is a basic structure for the cart items I'm creating, and if you run the snippet you will see the alert message with X value of this item, the decimal places are what I want to remove. Tried Math.round() on var total = 0; with no success.

I am not sure what the best method would be to implement here, rounding up or completely stripping the additional decimals is fine, I ultimately just want pricing to look like R10.00 <-- for example.

```js
var shoppingCart = []; //{Product Name, Product Price}

var Item = function(name, price, qty){
 this.name = name;
 this.price = price;
 this.qty = qty;
};

function addItemToCart (name, price, qty) {
 for (var i in shoppingCart){
  if (shoppingCart[i].name === name) {
   shoppingCart[i].qty += qty;
   alert("You have added another item to your cart!, your current total is: R" + totalCart() + " Including VAT.");
   return;
  }
 }
 var item = new Item(name, price, qty);
 shoppingCart.push(item);
 alert("You have successfully added an item to your cart!, your current total is: R" + totalCart() + " Including VAT.");
};

function totalCart() {
 var totalCost = 0;
 for (var i in shoppingCart){
  totalCost += shoppingCart[i].price * shoppingCart[i].qty * 1.15;
 }
 return totalCost;
};


function clearCart() {
 shoppingCart = [];
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');

body {
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.shop-item {
 border: solid lightgrey 0.1em;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.shop-item:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.99);
 transform: scale(0.99);
}

.shop-item ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.shop-item img {
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: auto;
}

.shop-item img:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}


.shop-item-price {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.row {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="column col-md-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded shop-item">
  <h4 class="shop-item-name">Intel® Celeron® G4900</h4>
  <img class="shop-item-image" src="../Images/Celeron.gif">
  <ul class="shop-item-details">
   <li>Intel® Celeron® Processor G Series</li>
   <li>Cores : 2</li>
   <li>Threads : 2</li>
   <li>Base Frequency : 3.10GHz</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="shop-item-price">R699.00</p> 
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">More details</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="addItemToCart('Intel Celeron G4900', 699, 1)">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `Math.floor(totalCost)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `toFixed`...

```
let nb = 100/7;
console.log(nb);
console.log(nb.toFixed(2));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code here math.round like this :

```
Math.round((num)*100) / 100
```